# Strange behavior with SQL Server returning decimals with no decimal values

Tags: c#, sql-server

We have a stored procedure that returns rows and when the DBA runs the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio the column for averages is returning decimal values with decimals (0.01). But when I call the stored procedure from C#, the values returned from the stored procedure is an integer (0).

Has anyone seen this weird behavior? Does anyone know how to return the full number back to C#?

Comment: sample code reading the db?

Comment: Impossible to say what the issue is unless you provide your code.

Comment: I'm in a locked down system.  I'd have to get a System Admin to copy the code over.  Sorry!  I hate it.  I know it's pretty shitty but that's the environment I'm working in.

Comment: It is nonsense to have even the simplest test code locked down.

Comment: Yes. The weird behavior is caused by the code. You need to fix the code.

Comment: I'd guess someone has declared the wrong data type in the application. It's not SQL Server's fault if an application is treating the data it has returned poorly.

Comment: I've gotten some help from another developer.  I'll post the answer to help someone else in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.  I'm a dumbass!  The DBA was running the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio and the column for averages does display decimal values with decimals (0.00) in SQL Management Studio.  But when 0.00 gets returned to C#, because those decimals have no value, the decimal is truncated.  However, in cases where a decimal value does exist (0.01) the decimal is not truncated.  That confused the hell out of me.